# How to add LoadMask on ContentPanel in GXT?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm using GXT 2.2.4.

Is there possibility to add LoadMask on ContentPanel (just like setLoadMask for Grid)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Grid.setLoadMask` function takes a boolean, and tells the grid that when the associated loader is pulling in more items (remote paging, sorting, filtering, etc), the `Component.mask(String)` and `Component.unmask()`. This can be built in because Grid understands having a loader that it can listen for events from (before load, load exception, load complete) to start and stop the mask.

In a `ContentPanel` or some other `Component` that doesn't have a built in loader, etc, you can still have this behavior - call something like `panel.mask("Loading...")` when the load starts, and `panel.unmask()` when it is complete.